# How can i sort tests by my liking?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, nunit

For example i got 3 test and their name are

```
[Test]
public void ATest()
{}

[Test]
public void BTest()
{}

[Test]
public void DTest()
{}
```

- How i can make show that i want to run them in this sort **DTest** to be **1st**, **ATest 2nd** and **BTest 3rd**?
- Only solution i found is to rename them in **Test1_DTest**, **Test2_ATest** and **Test3_BTest**.

Any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's the way to do it, by alphabetizing your test cases. Take a look at this

https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunit-3.0/+bug/740539

Quote from Charlie Pool, on of the main devs for nunit:

"Relying on alphabetical order is a workaround that you can use but it
is *not* documented and supported beyond the visual order of the
display. In theory it could change at any time. In practice it won't
change until NUnit 3.0, so you're pretty safe using it as a
workaround."

Alternatively you could try testng which has a nice "preserve-order" flag which you could use to ensure test case order execution.

Answer (score 4):

The idea with Unit Testing is that it's irrelevant which order they are ran in because tests are supposed to run independently of each other. If all the tests you have run have passed then you shouldn't care about the order. If a test fails your focus will be on fixing that test.

If the order of the tests really is important to you then like Alex said the only way to do it is by alphabetizing your tests. I've seen cases where people have put A, B, C etc at the start of similar naming tests, but this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JUnit 4.11  (the latest version) , I do believe there is a "alphebetical order' scheme that you can use to execute [in alphabetical order](http://randomallsorts.blogspot.com/2012/12/junit-411-whats-new-test-execution-order.html).  I'm not sure if NUnit has the same capability.

But, personally I will usually configure my build system , either Gradle or Maven, to execute certain test classes in atomic operations.  That way I can combine them in the order I need.